# Drive Capacitive load with toroidal transformer

Tags: operational-amplifier, transformer, load, 741-opamp, toroidal

this question is related to my previous post:
[Toroidal transformer voltage breaks down](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/510356/toroidal-transformer-voltage-breaks-down/510362?noredirect=1#comment1307649_510362)

I am trying to build a circuit that drives a capacitive load (approx. 9nF) through use of a toroidal transformer. My circuit generates a 2Vpp sine wave with variable frequency (50 - 500 Hz) and feeds it into a power amplifier OPAMP (OPA548), which is able to supply around 2 A at approx. 14V output voltage. My goal is to control the voltage on the capacitive load to increase and decrease both frequency and voltage.

My problem is that if I increase the frequency of my sine wave, my load impedance will decrease and draw more current. The primary winding inductance however will increase its impedance and therefore, I will get less current on this side.

Therefore, if I try to design the circuit for 50 Hz, I would need aprox. 0.06 A of input current, which is no problem. But when I then increase the frequency, I would need 10 times this current but the impedance on the primary side of the transformer will increase and thus I can not draw more current while maintaining the voltage levels[image].

Does anyone have a clue what I could do to prevent this?

EDIT: I use the transformer in reverse, meaning that for my application, the leakage inductance on the secondary winding is 10 H and gets shorted out by the capacitive load. My leakage inductance on the primary side will be around 9 mH. My problem is that for 500 Hz, I would need approx. 20 mA to drive my capacitive load at 400V which means I need to supply 666 mA at 12 V through my OPAMP. But when I decrase the frequency to 50 Hz, this would result in 6,6 A at 12V from my OPAMP and thus burning my OPAMP. Now since I do not have much experiance with using transformers over a this frequency range, are there any actions I could make to somehow "match" my input impedance or so to not burn my OPAMP while still being able to drive my load. Or is a sigma-delta amplifier better since amplifying different frquencies is more like audio technology?

A better schematic:
[image]

Comment: The primary inductance is in parallel with the transformed load, so it isn't the problem. What is the coupling factor between pri and sec; alternatively, what is the leakage inductance? ( = pri inductance measured with a short cct across the secondary).

Comment: I am pretty bad at working with transformers, but how are they parallel if the voltage drop across them is not equal?

For the transformer I only got the datasheet:
https://docs.rs-online.com/2ef1/0900766b8002aa69.pdf

It is an toridal transformer I use in reverse, so I want to transform a 12V voltage to a 400V voltage.

Comment: useful search term : "transformer equivalent circuit"

Comment: @RobertReichel Brian is quite correct, the 9 mH (as I calculated on the other question) is the magnetization inductance and is in parallel and therefore it doesn't impede the transfer. Maybe you should  search for transformer related Q and A's on this site to give a more detailed explanation such as [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/473554/equivalent-circuit-of-a-simple-transformer/473557#473557).

Comment: The only inductance you have to worry about is the leakage inductance, which will be very low for a toroidal. The magnetising inductance is 'shorted out' by the load, through transformer action, it's just like driving a turns^2 scaled version of your secondary at the primary.

Comment: @Andyaka, the 9 mH you calculated will be my "primary", since I use the transformer in reverse, the load will short the 10 H inductance on the other side. And this is what I think causes my problem, my OPAMP is not able to supply enough current through the transformer at 12 or 14V. Obviously, I wrote the question very confusing....

Comment: The load will not short things out. I don't see how you concluded that. Your basic problem is still trying to drive the 9 mH at 50 Hz as per your previous question.

Comment: @Andyaka I got the idea from Neil_UKs answer. I also thought that the basic problem is driving the 9 mH at 50 Hz, but even if I correct for this with maybe a different transformer with a higher inductance (my supervisor mentioned the possibility of buying a custom made transformer where we can "choose" the parameters within a certain range), I will get problems at 500 Hz through the higher inductance, so this is why I am asking if there is maybe a relatively simple method or circuit to compensate for this problem. If not, I will probably have to use a different approach.

Comment: So TL;DR:

If I use the current setup, it works with 500 Hz but at 50 Hz I can not drive my load.
If I change the transformer, it may work with 50 Hz but at 500 Hz the inductance will result in a bigger input impedance and therefore, I can not drive enough input current into the transformer to get the desired output current.

So is there some circuit that could help with that (I thought about adding some inductance to the output or something like that, but at resonance I will just short the whole thing)?

Comment: Well, I think Neil's comment is wrong so maybe ask him to clarify. Operating at a higher frequency can cause problems with leakage inductance (and resonance) on the secondary but, given that you are using LTSpice why don't you run a simulation and see for yourself.

Comment: I tried and it does not work. I also searched for some sort of impedance matching but this still does not work so I thought maybe someone here would have an idea on what type of circuit I could use. But currently I think the only solution would either be a much more powerful OPAMP or a completely different method...